# SQL Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'dbo'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a database use mysql workbench and I keep getting this error and my code looks fine. Not sure how I can resolve this. This is the error I am getting: Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'dbo'.
I have tried so many things but only the first two lines of creating and using the database works. [screenshot attached]

[image]

```
use employeedb;

create table dbo.Department(
DeprartmentId int AUTO_INCREMENT,
DepartmentName nvarchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentId)
);

insert into dbo.Department(DepartmentName) values ('IT');
insert into dbo.Department(DepartmentName) values ('Support');

create table dbo.Employee(
EmployeeId int AUTO_INCREMENT,
EmployeeName nvarchar(500),
Department nvarchar(500),
DateOfJoining datetime,
PhotoFileName nvarchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId)
);

insert into dbo.Employee(EmployeeName,Department,DateOfJoining,PhotoFileName) 
values                  ('John','IT','2022-11-27','anonymous.png');

select * from dbo.Employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are changing from MSSQL to MySQL, for MySQl do not need "dbo", just:

use employeedb;

create table Department(
DeprartmentId int AUTO_INCREMENT,
DepartmentName nvarchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentId)
);
....

Comment: I have done that and I now get this error: Error Code: 1072. Key column 'DepartmentId' doesn't exist in table

Comment: ...then why did you accept this answer as being correct?

Comment: It works now. Had to fix a typo(refer below). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using SQL Server syntax, which won't work on MySQL.  Here is your script updated for MySQL:

```sql
USE employeedb;

CREATE TABLE Department (
    DeprartmentId int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DepartmentName varchar(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentId)
);

INSERT INTO Department(DepartmentName) VALUES ('IT');
INSERT INTO Department(DepartmentName) VALUES ('Support');

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeId int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    EmployeeName varchar(500),
    Department varchar(500),
    DateOfJoining datetime,
    PhotoFileName varchar(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId)
);

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeName, Department, DateOfJoining, PhotoFileName) 
VALUES ('John', 'IT', '2022-11-27', 'anonymous.png');

SELECT * FROM Employee;
```

Comment: I have done that and I now get this error: Error Code: 1072. Key column 'DepartmentId' doesn't exist in table

Comment: I think you are not running the code in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it. There was a typo: "DepartmentId" not "DeprartmentId". Thank You!